# Callback on main thread when a thread finishes

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, callback

I need to get the main thread notified when a worker thread finishes. When I take a delegate and execute it on the other thread when it's finished, it get's executed on that thread, which is not what I want. Neither I can check for it to be finished due to some restrictions I have ('Update' in Unity Editor not called every frame). Are there any other options I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use async/await..

```
async void MyFunc()
{
    await Task.Run(() => { /* your work in thread */ });
    //Your work is finished at this point
}
```

And as a plus, you can surround it with try-catch block and catch the exceptions that may happen in your work in a smart way.

Comment: that probably would be the best solution, but Unity seems not to support it. Anyways, will mark it as correct because it's good and I found a different hackier solution: Fixed the Update-problem by subscribing to UnityEditor.EditorApplication.update which does get called every frame.

Comment: `async void` is dangerous, better use `async Task` as return type

Comment: This won't work (for obvious reasons, neither it did back when the answer was posted) in current version of Unity 5.4.x as the used Mono runtime is equivalent of .NET 3.5 and C# version is 3.0 with some features available from 4.0. Though, Unity are slowly gearing towards newer Mono runtime and C# version...

Answer (score 3):

```
//This is a helper coroutine
IEnumerable RunOffMainThread(Action toRun, Action callback) {
  bool done = false;
  new Thread(()=>{
    toRun();
    done = true;
  }).Start();
  while (!done)
    yield return null;
  callback();
}

//This is the method you call to start it
void DoSomethingOffMainThread() {
  StartCoroutine(RunOffMainThread(ToRun, OnFinished));
}

//This is the method that does the work
void ToRun() {
  //Do something slow here
}

//This is the method that's called when finished
void OnFinished() {
   //off main thread code finished, back on main thread now
}
```

Comment: Same problem as with default Update, unity editor does not call the coroutine every frame:(

Comment: I see, I didn't realize the problem was strictly in the editor.

Comment: Even if it doesn't work for Editor, this usage is a blast for Player!